# Query on find command

Tags: bash, shell, find

When i do a find inside a directory i get the output like

```
./MyWork/a.c
./MyWork/b.c
./mtab
```

My question is how can use find command in such a way that my output will not show `./`

my output should be

```
MyWork/a.c
MyWork/b.c
mtab
```

Thanks,
LinuxPenseur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-printf "%P\n"` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Couild you kindly explain how "find" output gets formatted by adding the code you suggested?